# can we display glass bar chart in python with google app engine

Tags: python

i am using bar chat and i want to use glass bar chart instead of that

tutorials are given for PHP only.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't know, what is "glass bar chart".

You cannot (or at least it is not effective to) generate graphics (charts) on the AppEngine servers. However, if you want to display bar charts or any other kind of plots and charts in your AppEngine applications, you have two other solutions:

A) Use an external chart plotting service to produce plots. Google Charts is a popular choice. There are some Python libraries which can help here:

- [pygooglechart](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/)
- [google-chartwrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/)
- [graphy](http://code.google.com/p/graphy/)

B) Plot anything on the client (use Javascript to plot charts). There are some Javascript libraries which may help you:

- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)
- and [many others](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+%28plotting+OR+chart%29+library)

Generally, A is easier and more accessible, but B can produce more eye-candy. If you need interactive charts, you should choose B.